# Manual Probe method of finding JTAG pinout

Tags: digital-logic, embedded, jtag, logic-level, pinout

There is manual [Probe method](http://www.riffbox.org/downloads/manuals/JTAG_Signals_Probing.pdf) of finding JTAG pinout on RIFF Box JTAG programmer, by measurement of voltage on JTAG pins while alternately setting on JTAG pins the logical level 1 and 0.
Is it possible use this method without the JTAG programmator hardware? (like RIFF, etc). If that's possible, how to set logic level 1 and 0 on JTAG pins? Is this possible via custom generator, and how to implement this? Can anyone show such generator diagram and manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like figuring out the pinout of the actual JTAG connector doesn't require any JTAG hardware. However, after you have the pinout, you need some sort of JTAG interface to proceed any further.

Comment: How they set Probe level signal to logic level '0' and '1'?

Comment: Jumper wire? Seems like the idea is to measure the pin voltage with a multimeter while applying external voltage through a resistor. Simply change whether you're connecting it to vcc or gnd to change the level.

Comment: One note: the Riff JTAG box have Probe cable with [Probe Needle](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/o0EAAOSwTZ1Xm8gb/s-l500.jpg), is this for measuring using Riff box built-in measurement software, not by external multimeter?

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense.  Most JTAG cables that I am familar with are pure JTAG (tdi, tdo, tms, tck, and maybe a reset) and have no analog functionality.  It looks like the cable can be used to speed some reverse-engineering operations.  But you should be able to do the same thing with a multimeter and a resistor.

Comment: If I/O pins voltage level is 3.3V: this is test voltage that need be applied directly to JTAG pad (after 10K resistor), or this voltage level is on the output of external power supply?(before 10K resistor)